# class variable not recognized in dojo request and data not display instantly

Tags: javascript, dojo

I wrote a class, `DataGridPane`, extended from a `ContentPane` which holds a data grid. I have the following problems:

- In dojo's `request.post.then` function, the `this.xxx` property variables are not recognized and show as `undefined`. Why is this happening?
- The table doesn't display the data until I drag a split line into the page.

```js
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
    'dojo/dom-construct',
    'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dojo/store/Memory',
    'gridx/Grid',
    'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync',
    'dojo/request',
    'dijit/Tooltip', 
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (
        declare, 
        ContentPane,
        DomConstruct, lang, Store, Grid, Cache, request, Tooltip) {

    DataGridPane = declare('DataGridPane', ContentPane, {
      id:                   "id",
      title:                undefined,
      url:                  undefined,
      requestType:          "json",
      gridContainer:        undefined,
      layout:               undefined,

      constructor:
        function(params) {
           //......
        },

      start: function() {           
           this.gridContainer = DomConstruct.create("div",{
              id:      "gridDiv"
           }, this.domNode);            
           this.createGrid();
      },

      createGrid:
            function() {
                //Q1:I have to save this.layout to another variable, as the following 
                //code in request.post.then didn't see all this.xxx variables
                var layout = this.layout;
                request.post( this.url, {      //Q1:this.url is OK
                      handleAs: this.urlType    //Q1:this.urlType is OK
                    }
                ).then(
                    // Q1:console.log print 3 'undefined'
                    console.log( this.url + this.urlType + this.layout); 
                    function(response){
                      var datalist = [];
                      var length = 0;

                      dojo.forEach(response.items, function(thisText, i){
                        datalist.push(lang.mixin({ id: i+1 }, thisText));  
                        length++;
                      });
                      var store = new Store({
                        data: datalist
                      });       

                      var grid = new Grid({
                        cacheClass: Cache,
                        store: store,
                        structure: layout
                      }, 'gridDiv');    

                      grid.startup();   
                   }, function(error){
                      console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
                   }
               );
            }
            .......
     });

     //Return the DataGridPane object.
     return DataGridPane;
});
```

Question 2 is about the response. I made the response the format below:

```
{
  "items":[...],
  "status":[...],
  "description":[...]
}
```

`response.items` hold the list to be show in the table cells; `response.status` and `response.description` carry 2 other lists I will use in tool tip. I include these 3 lists in one response instead of sending 3 separate requests to enhance efficiency. However, the table doesn't show anything when the page is loaded. The items in `response.items` only become visible once I have dragged the split line.

As an experiment, I used a simpler format of the response as follows:

```
 {
   "items":[...]    
 }
```

When `items` is the only element in the response, the items in `response.items` are displayed when the page is opened, but I'll fail to retrieve enough data for one request. Isn't the dojo request designed to parse the complicated response?

I have tried a call to `this.resize()` after `grid.startup()` but it appears to have no effect.

Comment: The code you've pasted has syntax errors. Double check and edit your answer. (The line with `console.log( this.url ... ` seems misplaced.) Also try to fix the indentation, it makes it easier for others to understand the program (keep in mind that stackoverflow doesn't handle <Tab> characters).

Comment: Hi, I re-edited the indention. I removed the comma after createGrid:function{} as in my original code, this is not the last method. But here, it's the last one and the comma should be removed. Sorry I posted the thread in such a haste, I'm eager to know the answer and the best way for me to do.

Comment: this.url and other class properties are initialized in the constructor. this.url points to a Perl script printing the Json response.

Comment: There's still syntax errors. You seem to have inserted a `console.log` statement in the parameter list for `.then()`. The class property problem (Q1) is a very common Javascript mistake, I advice you to read something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/ and then http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch .

Answer (score 0):

Comments get a bit cramped, so I'll expand a bit on the problems mentioned.

**Problem 0: Syntax errors (added by me)**

There are still syntax errors. You seem to have inserted a `console.log` statement in the parameter list for `.then()`. Remove that, so you'll have something like this:

```
).then(
    // Q1:console.log print 3 'undefined'
    // ------------> You can't have a console.log statement here,
    // ------------> this is the parameter list for then()!
    // console.log( this.url + this.urlType + this.layout); 
    function(response){
       ....
    }, 
    function(error){
       ....            
    });
```

**Problem 2: Class properties not working**

This is a very common Javascript mistake, I advice you to take a look at these:

- http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch

Essentially, one way to solve it is by making local variables, e.g. `var layout = this.layout;` like you've done (you'll often see people doing `var self = this;` also). This is because function scope and the `this` keyword work a little differently from what you're used to (see the aforementioned links).

Alternatively, you can use the `hitch()` function in `dojo/_base/lang` to "bind" the function to the `this` object. That would look something like the following:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/lang", // <--------- remember to add this
    /* your other dependencies here... */
], function (
    lang, // <!--------- this too!
    /* your other dependencies here as well, of course.. */
) {
// your other code as before ......

    request.post( this.url, {
            handleAs: this.urlType 
        }).then(
            lang.hitch(this, function(response) {
                // <--------- Now using this.layout etc works here
            }),
            function(error) { /* .... */ }
        );
```

**Problem 3: Grid not showing until you resize the pane**

This usually occurrs when the Grid tries to render itself in a DOM node that is detached from the DOM (or the node has `display: none` or similar). You can try to fix this by calling `grid._resize()` after you've inserted it in the DOM.

As a quick test, you can do something silly like (do **not** leave this in there though, it's just for determining the root cause):

```
setTimeout(function() { grid._resize(); }, 2000);
```

Edit: Ok, I see you've tried something similar, so this may not be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed reply which is very useful. However  `setTimeout` seems didn't resolve the problem 3. For 1, console.log is inserted in the wrong place when editing this post. I just compared with my own code. In my code it is in the function scope, not the parameter list. For 2, it's good to know the detail, thanks a lot.